# jQuery cortando palavras com espaço

Tags: php, jquery, json

Possuo uma tela onde as linhas são carregadas conforme os dados do banco e para isso possuo um PHP+jQuery e afins para a criação da mesma. O que ocorre é que o array que manda os dados vem corretamente, mas na hora da carga o campo só é alimentado pela primeira palavra, se houver espaços ele ignora. Abaixo segue:

**Array:**

```
[{"nome":"DIEGO LUIS VENUZKA","codigo":"5357","cracha":"6246286874","situacao":"ATIVO","ASO":"30\/04
\/18","id":"1","descricao":"PONTE ROLANTE (NR11 E NR12)","validade":"06\/05\/18"},{"nome":"DIEGO LUIS
 VENUZKA","codigo":"5357","cracha":"6246286874","situacao":"ATIVO","ASO":"30\/04\/18","id":"4","descricao"
:"EMPILHADEIRA A GAS (NR11 E NR12)","validade":"06\/05\/18"}]
```

**Parte do código que carrega os dados desse array:**

```
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
  HTML += "<tr><td><input type = 'text' size = '3' name = 'id[]' id = 'id[]' value=" + data[i].id + " readonly></td>";
  HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '40' name = 'descricao[]' id = 'descricao[]' value=" + data[i].descricao + " readonly></td>";
  HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '10' name = 'validade[]' id = 'validade[]' value=" + data[i].validade + " readonly></td>";
}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acontece que você não esta passando o valor dentro de aspas, exemplo:

```html
<input type="text" value=Stack Overflow Português />

<input type="text" value="Stack Overflow Português" />
```

Altere para:

```
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
  HTML += '<tr><td><input type="text" size="3" name="id[]" id="id[]" value="' + data[i].id + '" readonly></td>';
  HTML += '<td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" id="descricao[]" value="' + data[i].descricao + '" readonly></td>';
  HTML += '<td><input type="text" size="10" name="validade[]" id="validade[]" value="' + data[i].validade + '" readonly></td>';
}
```

Comment: Cara.....eu desde as 8hs me quebrando e tu me dá uma solução tão óbvia...que vergonha....hehehe. Muito obrigado!!!!!

Comment: Acontece, no meio de tantas aspas duplas e simples não tinha como faltar alguma.